# Laggy empty project at 60FPS

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
@Override
public void create() {
batch = new SpriteBatch();
img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
}

@Override
public void render() {
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
if (x < 0 || x > 400) {
    speed = -speed;
}
x += speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 60;
Gdx.app.log("delta",Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()+"");

batch.begin();
batch.draw(img, x, 0);
batch.end();
}
```

I had a problem and i created a new project. The problem libgdx tries to keep 60FPS and avarage deltatime is ~16ms.Some renders take +20ms then next render takes 12ms(render1 + render2 = 32ms) to achieves 60FPS. That makes game laggy. As you can see i don't have anything in the project and it is the same in desktoplaunch. How did you solve this ?

Note: I also tried reqeustRendering. But it is the same thing if the render takes more time than the average. I also tried to wait some time for the render if that is less than 16ms. It didn't help either. It doesn't have any GC problem. I use Libgdx 1.6.4.

Comment: Consider using a fixed time step and thus making the game framerate independent: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Comment: The code above is frame rate independent. A fixed timestep is for a repeatable physics simulation and would actually introduce stuttering unless it is combined with interpolation. Regarding the original question, I don't see any issues with what you're doing. Are you seeing uneven frame rate? Try using `Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime()` and see if that looks different. Sounds like you're getting performance spikes, but that would be unusual for such a basic program.

Comment: I used rawDeltaTime but it did not help. That sprite is jerky for 2 or 3 seconds for every ~5 seconds. Do you use 1.6.4 version ?

Comment: Yeah, I've used 1.6.4 for a couple weeks and haven't noticed any lag.

Comment: Could you please share the game class code ?

Answer (score 1):

## Do not log output in the render loop

Remove the line
`Gdx.app.log("delta",Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()+"");`
as this writes output to the log, which slows down your render loop dramatically.